# How transfer a selected option to another page in vue application?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

On the first page of my *Vue* application, I have a *drop-down menu* that contains a list of mailboxes.

I would like to save the value/text of the selection and use it as a parameter or variable on the *Inbox page* that I routed to.

Here is the drop-down code using [`v-autocomplete`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/):

```html
<v-autocomplete dense
  filled
  label="Choose Mailbox"
  v-model="mailboxes"
  :items="mailboxes"
  item-text='mailbox'
  item-value='mailbox'>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Here is the button as [`v-btn`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/) that routes to the *Inbox page*.

```html
<v-btn rounded color="primary" 
  @click="$router.push('Inbox')">
Load Mailbox</v-btn>
```

How do I save the selected mailbox value to use on the routed-to *Inbox page*?

Comment: Just to be sure before writing: is the "button page" a page whose route is triggered from the "dropdown page"?

Comment: @MarcosSandrini the v-btn is on the same page as the dropdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to get started with [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) :)

It's a library that share a reactive data object across the whole app.

Here is what it could look like for you:

```js
// /store/index.js

export state: () => {
   mailbox: '',
}

export mutation: () => {
   SET_MAILBOX(state, mailbox) {
      state.mailbox = mailbox
   }
}
```

```
// your-page.vue
<template>
    <v-autocomplete
        v-model="mailboxes"
        dense
        filled
        label="Choose Mailbox"
        :items="mailboxes"
        item-text='mailbox'
        item-value='mailbox'>
      </v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   computed: {
      mailboxes: {
         get() {
            this.$store.state.mailbox // Get the value from the Vuex store
         },
         set(newMailbox) {
            this.$store.commit('SET_MAILBOX', newMailbox) // Update the Vuex store
         },
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Passing the selected value as a route parameter:

```
$router.push({
    name: "Inbox",
    params: { selectedValue: YOUR_VALUE }
  });
```

In the Inbox page, you can access it through:

```
$route.params.selectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Other easy solution is to use browser local storage.
[Vue Client-Side Storage](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html)